# How UPDATES Work in SQL Server When Values of Columns Have Not Changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a quick question about updates that happen via s SQL Server stored procedure. My question is, if you explicitly use the `UPDATE` keyword in your stored procedure, that is looking at two different tables, for instance, will that `UPDATE` regardless of whether or not there is a difference in the values? Or will it ONLY run if there is a difference in values between columns? And will it selectively ONLY update the values that have changed, or the whole row, if it's found that any column is different between the two?

Comment: SQL Server will update the rows and log the results, even when the row does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ISO/ANSI SQL standards, all data manipulations, especially writings, must be done even if there is no changes in the values between the old and the new values…

To undestand why, thainks that this query :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Column1 = Column1
```

Will fire all the UPDATEs triggers and this will make a functionnal difference if the triggers had not been reached !

A +